# Which frontend technology knowledge is required for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend

To make a custom theme for Magento 2, which tools and technology is required?

**Example**

- Less
- Angular
- etc.

Answer (score 6):

Magento2 uses:

- Less
- JQuery Widgets
- RequireJS
- Knockout
- Underscore.js
- AngularJS (is used only in Setup Application)

You can find dev guides here:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/bk-javascript-dev-guide.html

Comment: Also add grunt to that , without it frontend development in magento is a real pain.

Comment: Grunt is not a default part of Magento2.